# How do I store a user prompt(input) into an array and retrieve it's max and min value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I'm trying to input values into a prompt, convert the values into integers, push the values into an array, and retrieve the min & max values from the array. I don't know wether to convert the user input into integers, or convert the array items into integers. I also need a way of splitting the array from 1 item into the size of the input. For example, user would enter into the prompt "1 2 10 40", and then be alerted that the min is 1, and the max is 40. The array length should be 4. Here's how the code that I'm tampering with:

```
var numInput = prompt("Enter a series of numbers with spaces in between each:");
var numArray = [];
numArray.push(numInput);
numInput.split(" ");
alert(Math.min(numArray));
alert(Math.max(numArray));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `.split` to the array variable.

`Math.min` and `Math.max` expect the numbers to be in separate arguments, not in an array. You can use `apply` to spread the array into arguments.

```js
var numInput = prompt("Enter a series of numbers with spaces in between each:");
var numArray = numInput.split(" ");

alert(Math.min.apply(null, numArray));
alert(Math.max.apply(null, numArray));
```

Comment: Thanks much for your help. That's one badass way of using prompts without resorting to using arrays and loops. This is super clean code!

Answer (score 0):

After you split the string you need to find the highest and lowest.

```js
var numInput = prompt("Enter a series of numbers with spaces in between each:");
var numArray = numInput.split(" ");
var max=Number.MIN_VALUE;
var min=Number.MAX_VALUE;
for(i=0;i<numArray.length;i++){
  if(parseInt(numArray[i])<min)
    min=parseInt(numArray[i]);
  if(parseInt(numArray[i])>max)
     max=parseInt(numArray[i]);
}
alert(min);
alert(max);
```